# Mysql:indexes and order of rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-order-by, sql-insert

Step 1:

I am creating a simple table.

```
CREATE TABLE `indexs`.`table_one` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

Step 2:

I make two inserts into this table.

```
insert into table_one (name) values ("B");
insert into table_one (name) values ("A");
```

Step 3:

I make a select, I get a table, the records in which are ordered by id.

```
SELECT * FROM table_one;
```

[image: results select]

This is the expected result, because in mysql the primary key is a clustered index, therefore the data will be physically ordered by it.

Now the part I don't understand.

Step 4:

I am creating an index on the name column.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_one(name)
```

I repeat step 3 again, but I get a different result. The lines are now ordered according to the name column.

[image: results select after creating index]

Why is this happening? why the order of the rows in the table changes in accordance with the new index on the name column, because as far as I understand, in mysql, the primary key is the only clustered index, and all indexes created additionally are secondary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I make a select, I get a table, the records in which are ordered by id. [...] This is the expected result, because in mysql the primary key is a clustered index, therefore the data will be physically ordered by it.

There is some misunderstanding of a concept here.

Table rows have no inherent ordering: they represent *unordered* set of rows. While the clustered index enforces a physical ordering of data in storage, it does not guarantee the order in which rows are returned by a `select` query.

If you want the results of the query to be ordered, then use an `order by` clause. Without such clause, the ordering or the rows is *undefined*: the database is free to return results in whichever order it likes, and results are not guaranteed to be consistent over consecutive executions of the same query.

```
select * from table_one order by id;
select * from table_one order by name;
```

Comment: You have misunderstood me, or I have expressed myself incorrectly. After I create an index for the name column, the entries themselves are sorted alphabetically after insertion. Although they should be ordered by id, because it is a cluster index.

Comment: Doesn't the cluster index guarantee that the disk records will be stored in a certain sequence?

Comment: @user373699: I understand your question. But, as explained in my order, the ordering of the rows in your result is actually undefined if you don't put an `order by` clause. It may change in the future, regardless of the indexes that you have, or don't have.

Comment: @user373699: the cluster index enforces the physical order of rows, which speeds up searches, but does not provide an implicit `order by`for your resultset.

Comment: @user373699: I edited my answer to be more specific about the index vs the ordering of the resultset.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes. I changed that part of my answer to be (hopefully) more precise.

Answer (score 3):

(GMB explains most)

> Why is this happening? why the order of the rows in the table changes in accordance with the new index on the name column

Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` -- it might give a clue of what I am about to suggest.

You added `INDEX(name)`.  In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` column(s) are tacked onto the end of each secondary index.  So it is effectively a BTree ordered by `(name,id)` and containing only those columns.

Now, the Optimizer is free to fetch the data from the index, since it has everything you asked for (id and name).  (This index is called "covering".)

Since you did not specify an `ORDER BY`, the result set ordering is valid (see GMB's discussion).

**Moral of the story:**  If you want an ordering, specify `ORDER BY`.  (The Optimizer is smart enough to "do no extra work" if it can see how to provide sorted results without doing an extra sort.

Further experiment:  Add another column to the table but don't change the indexes.  Now you will find `SELECT * FROM t` is ordered differently than `SELECT id, name FROM t`.  I think I have given you enough clues to predict this difference, if not, ask.